# Count the number of duplicate for a column

Tags: r

My objective is to get a count on how many duplicate are there in a column.
So i have a column of 3516 obs. of 1 variable,
 there are all dates with about 144 duplicate each from 1/4/16 to 7/3/16.
 Example:(i put 1 duplicate each for example sake)
1/4/16
1/4/16
31/3/16
31/3/16
30/3/16
30/3/16
29/3/16
29/3/16
28/3/16
28/3/16
so i used the function date = count(date)
where date is my df date.
But once i execute it my date sequence is not in order anymore. 
 Hope someone can solve my problem.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to create another column and hav the number of duplicate beside the date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we need to count the total number of duplicates

```
sum(table(df1$date)-1)
#[1] 5
```

---

Suppose, we need the count of each date, one option would be to group by 'date' and get the number of rows.  This can be done with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .N, date]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want the count of number of duplicates in your column , you can use `duplicated`

```
sum(duplicated(df$V1))
#[1] 5
```

Assuming `V1` as your column name.

**EDIT**

As per the update if you want the count of each data, you can use the `table` function which will give you exactly that

```
table(df$V1)

#1/4/16 28/3/16 29/3/16 30/3/16 31/3/16 
#  2       2       2       2       2
```

Comment: i apologise if i didn't phrase my question properly, My expected output is to erase the duplicate and have another column that list the number of duplicate that was counted

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df%>% get_dupes(Variable) %>% tally()
```

You can add `group_by` in the pipe too if you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a data frame with unique values of your initial data which will preserve the order and then use `left_join` from `dplyr` package to join the two data frames. Note that the name of your column should be the same.

```
Initial_data <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1/4/16", "28/3/16", "29/3/16", "30/3/16", 
"31/3/16"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

df1 <- unique(Initial_data)
count1 <- count(df1)

left_join(df1, count1, by = 'V1')
#       V1 freq
#1  1/4/16    2
#2 31/3/16    2
#3 30/3/16    2
#4 29/3/16    2
#5 28/3/16    3
```

Comment: Error: `by` can't contain join column `V1` which is missing from RHS

Answer (score -1):

if you want to count number of duplicated records use:

```
sum(duplicated(df))
```

and when you want to calculate the percentage of duplicates use:

```
mean(duplicated(df))
```